# yarn command that adds integrity-sha to old yarn.lock file but do not upgrade any packages

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-lock.json

Is there any combination of yarn commands i can use so that in a old yarn.lock file we can add just the integrity-sha's but it doesn't upgrade any underlying packages.

Answer (score 1):

On versions less than 2.0

.yarnrc file:

```
unsafe-disable-integrity-migration false
```

Then run yarn again